# Erro GetAll: Calling ShapedQueryExpression.VisitChildren is not allowed

Tags: c#

**DETALHES**

Estou utilizando .NET Core 3.1 e MySql 8.0

Estou começando um projeto novo utilizando uma database MySql no [Digital Ocean](https://www.digitalocean.com/).

Estou utilizando o DDD, usei como base para fazer a estrutura este [site](https://medium.com/@alexalvess/criando-uma-api-em-net-core-baseado-na-arquitetura-ddd-2c6a409c686).

Criei um `ObterTodos()` para fazer os testes com a database no Digital Ocean.

**PROBLEMA**

Ao tentar dar um `ObterTodos()` no `Swagger`, recebo um este erro: `Calling ShapedQueryExpression.VisitChildren is not allowed. Visit expression manually for relevant part.`

Fiz um teste, onde criei um banco de dados SQL Server local, executei os create table, adaptei o projeto para receber a string de conexão do SQL Server (UseSqlServer(...)) e funcionou... O ObterTodos não deu erro!

**IMAGENS**

Este é o erro no Visual Studio:
[image: Erro no Visual Studio]

Este é o erro no Swagger:
[image: Erro no Swagger]

**CODIGO**

Controller:

```
[HttpGet("ObterTodos/")]
public IActionResult Get()
{
    try
    {
        return new ObjectResult(service.Get());
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return BadRequest(ex);
    }
}
```

Service:

```
public IList<T> Get() => repository.ObterTodos();
```

Repository:

```
protected Contexto context;
protected DbSet<T> DbSet;

public BaseRepository()
{
    context = new Contexto();
    DbSet = context.Set<T>();
}

public IList<T> ObterTodos()
{
    return DbSet.ToList();
}
```

Context:

```
public class Contexto : DbContext
{
    public static readonly ILoggerFactory MyLoggerFactory = LoggerFactory.Create(builder =>
    {
        builder
            .AddFilter((category, level) =>
                category == DbLoggerCategory.Database.Command.Name
                && level == LogLevel.Information)
            .AddConsole();
    });

    public DbSet<Usuario> Usuario { get; set; }
    public Contexto() : base() { }
    public Contexto(DbContextOptions<Contexto> options) : base(options) { }
    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        optionsBuilder
            .UseLoggerFactory(MyLoggerFactory)
            .UseMySql("Server=MINHACONEXAO.ondigitalocean.com;Port=PORTADIGITALOCEAN;Database=AppDb;Uid=leonardo;Pwd=MINHASENA");
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Usuario>(new UsuarioMap().Configure);
    }
}
```

Model:

```
public class Usuario : BaseEntity
{
    public string Senha { get; set; }
    public long? PessoaId { get; set; }
    public string PerfilAcesso { get; set; }
}
```

BaseEntity:

```
public abstract class BaseEntity
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime? DataCadastro { get; set; }
    public DateTime? DataAlterado { get; set; }
    public DateTime? DataInativado { get; set; }
    public long? UsuarioCadastroId { get; set; }
    public long? UsuarioAlteradoId { get; set; }
    public long? UsuarioInativadoId { get; set; }
    public string Exclusao { get; set; }
}
```

Map:

```
public class UsuarioMap : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Usuario>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Usuario> builder)
    {
        builder.ToTable("Usuario");

        builder.HasKey(c => c.Id);

        builder.Property(c => c.Senha)
            .IsRequired()
            .HasColumnName("Senha")
            .HasMaxLength(100);
        builder.Property(c => c.PessoaId)
            .HasColumnName("PessoaId");
        builder.Property(c => c.PerfilAcesso)
            .IsRequired()
            .HasColumnName("PerfilAcesso")
            .HasMaxLength(20);
        builder.Property(c => c.DataCadastro)
            .HasColumnName("DataCadastro");
        builder.Property(c => c.DataAlterado)
            .HasColumnName("DataAlterado");
        builder.Property(c => c.DataInativado)
            .HasColumnName("DataInativado");
        builder.Property(c => c.UsuarioCadastroId)
            .HasColumnName("UsuarioCadastroId");
        builder.Property(c => c.UsuarioAlteradoId)
            .HasColumnName("UsuarioAlteradoId");
        builder.Property(c => c.UsuarioInativadoId)
            .HasColumnName("UsuarioInativadoId");
        builder.Property(c => c.Exclusao)
            .HasColumnName("Exclusao")
            .IsRequired()
            .HasMaxLength(1);
    }
}
```

MySQL Query (Create Table Usuario)

```
CREATE TABLE Usuario(
    Id bigint auto_increment primary key,
    Senha VARCHAR(100) not null,
    PessoaId bigint,
    PerfilAcesso varchar(20) not null,
    DataCadastro DateTime,
    DataAlterado DateTime,
    DataInativado DateTime,
    UsuarioCadastroId bigint,
    UsuarioAlteradoId bigint,
    UsuarioInativadoId bigint,
    Exclusao CHAR(1) not null,
    FOREIGN KEY (UsuarioCadastroId)
    REFERENCES Usuario(Id),
    FOREIGN KEY (UsuarioAlteradoId)
    REFERENCES Usuario(Id),
    FOREIGN KEY (UsuarioInativadoId)
    REFERENCES Usuario(Id)
);
```

Comment: Em que linha do código acontece o erro?

Comment: @LeandroAngelo nesta aqui `public IList<T> Get() => repository.ObterTodos();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bom, não tive progresso com esse problema então desfiz o que tinha com a Digital Ocean e fui para o Google Cloud onde la tem o SQL Server.
Após fazer toda a configuração necessária para acessar o SQL Server do Cloud da Google e tambem o projeto para aceitar o SQL Server, funcionou tranquilamente.

Agradeço qualquer tentativa de ajuda, mesmo que não tenha efetivamente postado nada aqui, mas tenho certeza que foram atras pra tentar ajudar.